# Load image as blob into ListView

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, firedac

I am trying to load an image as blob into a ListView.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Pictures](
[PicId] INT, 
[UsersImage] BLOB);
```

Code:

```
procedure LoadFromBlob;
var
  BlobStream: TStream;
begin

  Form4.FDConnection1.Connected := True;

  try
    Form4.FDQuery1.Active := True;
    Form4.viewimgquery.Active := True;
    Form4.FDQuery1.Open;
    Form4.viewimgquery.Open;
    Form4.viewimgquery.First;
    while (not Form4.viewimgquery.EOF) do
    begin
      // access a stream from a blob like this
      BlobStream := Form4.viewimgquery.CreateBlobStream
        (Form4.viewimgquery.FieldByName('UsersImage'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
      // access a string from a field like this
      if (Form4.viewimgquery.FieldByName('PicId')
        .AsInteger = Form4.FDQuery1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger) then
      begin
        // load your blob stream data into a control
        Form4.viewimage.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
        Form4.ListView1.items.Add();
        BlobStream.Free;
        Form4.viewimgquery.Next;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      // ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
  end;
  Form4.FDConnection1.Connected := False;

end;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM PICTURES
WHERE PICID = :PicId
```

If I change it to `select * from pictures` and set query to active at design time I see all images loaded into the ListView so my live bindings are set up correctly. But when I call the procedure nothing is loaded into the ListView.

Comment: I don't think you're adding anything as 'Form4.Listview1.items.add()' isn't adding anything..shouldn't you be adding something :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to add the numbers from PicId  IE: Form4.ListView1.Items.AddItem(Form4.FDQuery1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);   but still noting in the list view.